# How can I login linux using C or C++

Tags: c++, linux

I need to programmely switch the current user to another,then the followed code should be executed in the environment(such as path,authority..) of another user. 
I've find the 'chroot()','setuid()' may be associated with my case, but these functions need the root authority, I don't have root authority, but I have the password of the second user. what should I do?

I have tried shell "su - " can switch current user, can this command help me in my C++ code?

Don't laugh at me if my question is very stupid, I'm a true freshman on linux. :)
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to run some external script/program as a different user or just some piece of code in your program itself?

Do you just need to run it with a different user id or do you also need the complete enviroment of the other user?

Comment: 1. I have this problem because I'm useing a third-part sdk or a geoscience software, with different users logged in, the results of the some sdk(api) functions are defferent, So, I think switch users to run some piece of code.
2. I need the complete enviroment of the other user.

Comment: To be honest i would recommend that you try to figure out why the results are different before starting to build such an ugly hack.

Try to nail down what is the difference between the two users. You could for example compare the user environments (perhaps some enviroment variable isn't set) and the config files (often hidden in files/directories starting with a .)

Comment: The geo software managements its data security by linux authority, That means the user can only open projects owned by him.
but now I want develop a data server, when clients connect to the server, the server transfer the data what they need,but the precondition is the correct username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when clients connect to the server,
>   the server transfer the data what they
>   need,but the precondition is the
>   correct username and password.

If your primary requirement is to authenticate, then try `man pam`. There are also some libraries allowing to auth over LDAP. Unfortunately I have no personal experience implementing neither.

Otherwise, recreating complete user environment is unreliable and error prone. Imaging a typo or endless loop but in user's ~/.profile.

I haven't done that for some time, but I would also have tried to dig in direction of "su", figuring out user shell (from /etc/passwd) and trying to exec() it as if it was a login shell (with "-"). But after that you would need somehow to communicate a command for execution to it and that's a problem: shells run differently in batch more and in interactive mode. As a possible hack, expect (`man expect`) comes to mind, but it is still IMO too unreliable.

I have in past used `ssh` under `expect` (to input the password), but it was breaking on customized user profiles every other time. With `expect`, to send a command, one has to recognize somehow that shell has finished initialization (execution of profile and rc files). But since many people customize the shell prompt and their profile/rc files print extra info, it was quite often that `expect` was recognizing shell prompt too soon.

BTW, depending on number of users, one can try a setup where users manually start the server under their own account. The server would have access only to the information which is only accessible to the user.

Comment: Very useful infomation,thanks very much.If I find a good solution, I will let you know..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system function to execute shell commands on the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the source code of the login command, or you could try using the exec()-family functions to call on login.

EDIT: Seems like you will need root access in any case.

Comment: Thanks! 
I think I should call exec("su - USERA...."),but I also want to know, when the exec return, if the environment of the thread will switch to the user's who called 'exec()',or keeps the USERA's..

Comment: When you call exec() the calling process image will be completely replaced with whatever you have executed. If you want to go this way you will need to fork a copy of you process which will then call exec().

Answer (score 1):

Is [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) what you're looking for?

Comment: No, setuid need the root access.

Comment: Follow the link. The setuid file flag switches the current user to the owner of the file. It is a security risk but might in your case be the correct solution. Implement your program to work via stdin/stdout, store it with setuid set for the correct user and then access the program (i.e. via system() or exec()) from whereever you need the information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key point here is that you can't change the user of the running process (easily). All the programs like 'su' are effectively starting a new process as the specified user.

Therefore, in your design I would recommend seperating off the functionality that needs to be done into a different executable and then investigate using execve() to start it.